# Search more them one term in match MySQL

Tags: mysql, match

How can I search for 'Red Carpet' parameter?

```
SELECT videos.*
FROM videos
WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST('+Red Carpet -Tshirt' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: What results do you get?Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrases should be quoted in `"` characters:

```
WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST('+"Red Carpet" -Tshirt' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```